# Conditional Table Selection in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to access data from different tables at once, but I'd like to be able to determine which tables to pull data from given the value of a column in another table.

Here is an example:

Table A: (id, table1_id, table1_type, table2_id, table2_type)

- (1, 1, 'B_Type', 2, 'E_Type')
- (2, 2, 'B_Type', 3, 'D_Type')
- (3, 1, 'C_Type', 2, 'B_Type')

Tables B: (id, some_values):

- (1, 'something')
- (2, 'something else')

Table C, D, and E look somewhat similar to B.

So, I'd like to do the following (done in pseudo javascript):

```
result = db.Query("SELECT * from A WHERE [condition] LIMIT 1")
table1 = getTable(result.table1_type) // E.g. 'B' if 'B_Type'
table2 = getTable(result.table2_type)
new_results = db.Query("SELECT * from " + table1 + ", " + table2 + "  WHERE [condition]")
```

This way works, but I was hoping there might be a way to conditionally select tables depending on A's table_type columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you need the ugliest of all multi-joins:

```
SELECT
  IF(A.table1_type='B',B1.some_value,
    IF(A.table1_type='C',C1.some_value,
      IF(A.table1_type='D',D1.some_value,
        IF(A.table1_type='E',E1.some_value,
          NULL)))) AS table1_value,
  IF(A.table2_type='B',B2.some_value,
    IF(A.table2_type='C',C2.some_value,
      IF(A.table2_type='D',D2.some_value,
        IF(A.table2_type='E',E2.some_value,
          NULL)))) AS table2_value
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B AS B1 ON A.table1_type='B' AND A.table1_id=B1.id
  LEFT JOIN C AS C1 ON A.table1_type='C' AND A.table1_id=C1.id
  LEFT JOIN D AS D1 ON A.table1_type='D' AND A.table1_id=D1.id
  LEFT JOIN E AS E1 ON A.table1_type='E' AND A.table1_id=E1.id
  LEFT JOIN B AS B2 ON A.table2_type='A' AND A.table2_id=B2.id
  LEFT JOIN C AS C2 ON A.table2_type='B' AND A.table2_id=C2.id
  LEFT JOIN D AS D2 ON A.table2_type='C' AND A.table2_id=D2.id
  LEFT JOIN E AS E2 ON A.table2_type='D' AND A.table2_id=E2.id
WHERE [condition for A];
```

**EDIT**

Some words of explanation: MySQL (as most SQL databases) have no "intended" way to dynamically switch between tables. This makes it necessary to join **all** tables, then drop all but one of the results. Repeat twice for your use case.

Comment: Wow, this is a horrible beast. How is the performance of this thing?

Comment: The horrible beast has horrible performance in most cases. There are cases, where this does make sense though: Imagine server and client being on different ends of the world with a very slow connection AND the tables being acceptably small AND the server being fast: The horrible query with one round-trip might easily be faster than the three natural queries with their three round-trips

Comment: That query is both impressive and disappointing. I'll see if I can't change around my schema a bit. Thanks for this.

Comment: @funseiki If this is possible, do so. The "horrible beast" is just a theoretical excersize in most scenarios. My recommendation is, to collapse tables B,C,D and E into one with a marker field and just NULL the unused fields - this works better than it sounds, I use it quite offten for "object->property" types of problem.

Comment: @EugenRieck I thought to do just that earlier, but didn't necessarily like the idea of not being able to enforce 'not null' for certain attributes.

But I may just need to suck it up and change things around.

Comment: @funseiki You can enforce the not NULL in a trigger - I always do it this way: Let the trigger check the type-marker, then check the values according to the logic for this object type. Put this in a BEFORE INSERT and a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, and you are done.

Comment: @EugenRieck, Ah, yeah that sounds great. I may also just create subtables referencing the main table as a foreign key. This'll require joins on lookup for Type_B specific attributes, but it at least keeps the tables separate.

Enforcing attribute constraints on triggers also sounds good - I'd probably need to do it even if I chose to 'sub-class' the tables anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using a cursor and some dynamic SQL if you want to avoid doing a bunch of joins.

Here is an example (this is written using MSSQL syntax but I think its close if not the same in MySql):

```
CREATE TABLE #result
(table1Val varchar(50), table2Val varchar(50))

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @table1_val int, @table1_type varchar(50), @table2_val int, @table2_type varchar(50)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT table1_id, table1_type, table2_id, table2_type
FROM A

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @table1_val, @table1_type, @table2_val, @table2_type

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = '
        INSERT INTO #result
        (SELECT val FROM ' +CASE @table1_type WHEN 'B_Type' THEN 'B' WHEN 'C_type' THEN 'C' + ' WHERE id = '''+@table1_val+'''),
        (SELECT val FROM ' +CASE @table2_type WHEN 'B_Type' THEN 'B' WHEN 'C_type' THEN 'C' + ' WHERE id = '''+@table2_val+''')
    '
    EXEC(@sql)
    --use this instead to debug the dynamic query
    --PRINT(@sql)
END
    UPDATE @JoinResult
    SET B_ID = SQ.ID,
        B_Age = SQ.AGE,
        B_Education = SQ.Education
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, AGE, EDUCATION
        FROM TableB b
        WHERE (
            abs((SELECT A_Age FROM @JoinResult WHERE A_Id = @i) - AGE) <=2
            AND abs((SELECT A_Education FROM @JoinResult WHERE A_Id = @i) - EDUCATION) <=2
        ) AND (SELECT B_ID FROM @JoinResults WHERE B_ID = b.id) IS NULL
    ) AS SQ 

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
SELECT #result
DROP TABLE #result
```